# Leaflet - Draw vector layer behind tile layer

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tile-layer

I'm using Leaflet to create a map in which I need to render a tile layer on top of a GeoJSON layer:

```
L.geoJson(...).addTo(map);
L.tileLayer(...).addTo(map);
```

The Tile Layer should be render on top.

---

I have use `setZIndex` and `brinToBack`/`bringToFront` methods without success. I have read that GeoJSON ordering in Leaflet relies on rendering SVG and maybe it's not possible to do that.

So the question is: **It's possible to render a GeoJSON layer behind a TileLayer?**

Comment: Yes, see concept of Leaflet map panes. https://leafletjs.com/examples/map-panes/

Comment: Yes! It was strange to me this wouldnt be supported in Leaflet. Thank you! Write an answer and I'll accept It.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet manages ordering of different types of layers through concept if map panes, which are DOM `div` elements with different z-index attribute. Tile layers are assigned to `tilePane` with `z-index` value of 200 and vector layers to `overlayPane` with `z-index` value of 400. That's the reason why changing layer's `z-index` doesn't help, since it operates within it's own map pane.

Apart from standard map panes, user can create his/her own map pane with `map.createPane` method, assign desired `z-index` value to it and then, when creating layer, assign layer to it via `pane` option.

In your case that could go something like this:

```
map.createPane('myPane');
map.getPane('myPane').style.zIndex = 500;
L.tileLayer({
  pane: 'mayPane',
  .
  .
  .
}).addTo(map);
```